# Unable to start activity NullPointerException-onActivityCreated

Tags: android, fragment

My App crash rarely
i want to get off this bug for ever.

this is the log that users Report

i tried so long on this but nothing helps

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity         ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.Master_}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2072)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1207)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.xxx.xxx.HomeFragment.onActivityCreated(HomeFragment.java:140)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1097)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1895)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2045)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Without some code the Stackoverflow community wont be able to help you.

Comment: Please check your code at `line number 140` on `HomeFragment.java` or provide your source code

Comment: thx alot textview.setText(R.string.add); 
it need to betextview.setText(context. getResources.getString(R.string.add));

Comment: can you please post HomeFragment ? which is better to identify your problem...

Comment: @Jehad include the source-code of `HomeFragment.java` in your post